# Scroll bar in the main section of a v-app

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have copied one of the pre-defined layouts from https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined.

However when the content of the main section overflows it cause a scroll to appear for the whole app, rather than a local scroll to the main section. Here is an example:

```
<template>
    <v-app toolbar footer>

        <v-toolbar class="blue darken-3" dark>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-navigation-drawer permanent clipped light absolute>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <main>
            <v-container>
                <p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p><p>hi</p>
            </v-container>
        </main>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

I've tried adding `class="scroll-y"` and `style="max-height: 100%"` to various sections with no progress.

What do I need to specify for the scroll to only affect the main section?

Answer (score 12):

This issue work for me, just adding

```
<style>
  html { overflow-y: auto }
</style>
```

to your style file.

Full documentation [hide scroll bar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: adding style directly to the root element html will also add to all other pages, hence this doesn work for a particular `view`

Answer (score 6):

I found this to work for the issue I was having:

```css
    html{
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

You can put that in your App.vue file, or in the projects index.html target file

Comment: Thank you,but It is not work , the scrollbar is still there,

Answer (score 5):

This solution work for me :

```
 mounted: function() {
    let elHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
    elHtml.style.overflowY = 'auto'
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    let elHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
    elHtml.style.overflowY = null
  },
```

Add this code in you file App.js

Comment: This is the answer that works even if scrollbar appears later, like when using NavigationDrawers

Answer (score 0):

look for index.html in your files and open it,
then add to the bottom of it:

```
html{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
#parent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I am sure you can figure out how to implement this, you simply make sure your main parent does not scroll and apply an overflow-y to the element that you do want to scroll inside of.